# How do you compute the smallest power that a matrix can be raised to in order for it to be equal to zero?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in an elementary differential equations class, and we have a question as part of our homework that asks us "to determine the smallest $k$ such that $(A- \lambda I)^k = 0$". We are given that the matrix $A$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I am unsure of how to solve for the value of $k$. I tried manually computing some powers of the matrix but I don't know how long it will take me to get to zero. The other part of the problem asks us to compute $e^{tA}$ given that $e^{tA} = e^{\lambda t} [I + t(A-\lambda I) +\frac{t^2}{2!}(A-\lambda I)^2 + ... ]$, but I can't figure out how to manipulate that to help me either.

I feel that I am missing something small and fundamental because this question feels like it should be easier than I am making it. I appreciate your help!

edit: One of the matrices is:  $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -4 & -4 \end{bmatrix} $.

Comment: On your homework. what is $A$ -- do you know it's values, or the ODEs it can be constructed from?

Comment: What is the size of $A$?

Comment: If it's an $n \times n$ matrix, the smallest $k$ is at most $n$.  If you're calculating this by hand, I suspect $n$ is not more than $3$ or $4$, so it should be quite feasible to compute the powers one by one.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity! I didn't know if giving the matrix would be too much information; I didn't want to seem like I was just looking for an answer. There are several matrices in the problem, and all are either 3x3 or 4x4. I will add one of them to my question.

Comment: You are given a matrix $A$ but what about its single eigenvalue $\lambda$? If $\lambda$ isn't an integer, then $(A-\lambda I)^k$ will be hard to calcuate by hand.

Comment: Hint: this is related to the dimension of the eigenspace of $\lambda$. As far as computing the exponential is concerned, the fact that $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent means that the series terminates after a finite number of terms.